# Lazy load Spring web page from Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I currently have a web page that displays some text and a set of images. In my Spring controller, I have two Java functions that retrieve this data however, the images take considerably longer to load and nothing appears on the web page until the images have been loaded. Is there a way to lazy load a web page from the Spring controller? Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/location/{city}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData(@PathVariable("city") String city, Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("cityName", city);
        Dashboard.getTextData(city, true);
        Dashboard.getImages(city);
        return "location";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can go with Asynchronous methods, Asynchronous(CompletableFuture interface) methods provide multi-thread from which we can load an image, while the main thread will do its other work other than the loading the image.
for asynchronous methods in spring, you can refer this [asynchronous methods](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)